# How do you make HTML elements appear on a vertical line using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Image of the problem:

[image]

How do I go from the one on the left, to the one on the right, using CSS?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Why can't you use a ``table``? Semantically it would be perfectly valid.

Comment: I know you said you wanted the solution in all CSS, but this is a textbook case for using a `table`.

Comment: Either you use `<table>` or `<div>` and style it with CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>You own</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>20</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>BPS</td>
        <td>0.50</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

or floating `div`s:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">You own</div>
    <div style="float:left;">20</div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">Price</div>
    <div style="float:left;">20</div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">BPS</div>
    <div style="float:left;">0.50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I used your last example, and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div id="left"> <!-- float left -->
        <p>You Own></p>
        <p>Price</p>
        <p>BPS</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right"> 
        <p>20</p>
        <p>20</p>
        <p>0.50</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two divs

```
<div class="box">
 Your own:<br />
 Price:<br />
 PBS
</div>

<div class="box">
 20<br />
 20<br />
 50
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
 float:left;
 padding-right:40px;
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that this in terms of accessibility breaks the context for vision impaired people who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

While I am in agreement that this can be a table, you can easily do this with floats.

```css
.container {
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 200px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.button {
    background: #efefef;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.item-header {
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width: 45%;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="button">Buy Foreign Worker</div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item-header">You Own:</div>
        <div class="item-value">20</div>
        <div class="item-header">Price:</div>
        <div class="item-value">20</div>
        <div class="item-header">BPS:</div>
        <div class="item-value">0.5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All you are doing is making the header values float to the left, and the clear ensures that it starts on a new row.